# Installing BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I am running into problems installing BeautifulSoup4. This is the code I am using in a Jupiter notebook to import beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import beautifulsoup4
import pandas as pd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 2
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 import beautifulsoup4
      3 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

When pip installing in terminal I get following output which states that beautiful soup should be installed:

```
(CodingFolder) user ~ % pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/CodingFolder/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/CodingFolder/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.3.2.post1)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` ?

Comment: Can you try importing this way:

 `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Found on [beautifulsoup4 doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: `pip install beautifulsoup4` or `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install with:

```bash
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and then you should be using this import statement:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

not:

```
import beautifulsoup4
```

[Installing and importing BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-beautiful-soup).

Answer (score -1):

To Install write

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and then import as

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

For more information refer https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/